# Set OneToMany relation in Laravel with exception in relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, one-to-many

I've create to tables with OneToMany relation. Two tables are `Malls` and `Shops`. Each `Mall` can have many `Shop` but the problem is each `Shop` is not necessarily belongs to a `Mall`. It can be a stand alone shop.

When I call `App\Shop::first()->mall` if the shop doesn't belongs to a `Mall` would it return `null` or throws exception or error?

How is it possible in Eloquent?

Comment: that's a thing you could learn just trying to see what happens. Eloquent returns NULL since no mall related to a Shop was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's understand your situation, You have Mall Model and Shop Model. One Mall may have multiple shop, while Shop may or may not belong to mall

Here is the code for Mall Model

```
public function shop() {
   return $this->hasMany(Shop::class);
}
```

Here is the code for Shop Model

```
public function mall(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Mall::class);
}
```

This will fulfil your requirement. Whenever a shop doesn't belong from any mall it will return null not an error.

Answer (score 1):

When you access **App\Shop::first()->mall**, Eloquent tries to load the related **mall** model using the value stored in **mall_id** property of your **Shop**. If it contains a value, related object is loaded if exists. If not, **NULL** is returned. If it doesn't contain any value, then again **NULL** is returned as there can't be a related record with such ID.